# Public access on my own git server

Tags: git, apache

I create my own git server following the [official how-to](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server). SSH access works perfectly while my computer SSH key is on the server. But I'd like to add a public access (to be able to do `git clone http://site.com/git.git` without any key or password). To do this I read this [part of the tutorial](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Public-Access).

1. My first question is for the group owner. I don't have a `www-data` group but a `http` group so I put this one. Can it be wrong ?
2. My second question is about the `vhost.conf` file. I have a gitweb vhost which look like this.

The vhost file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.git.site.com  
    ServerAlias git.site.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/git"  
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/git"  
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/git" common  
    <Directory /srv/http/git>  
       Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddHandler cgi-script cgi
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've to put this code :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName git.gitserver
    DocumentRoot /opt/git
    <Directory /opt/git/>
        Order allow, deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What's gitserver ? And can I merge this code with the gitweb vhost because I think that gitserver = site.com ? And how ?

Comment: I assume all the "//" here need to be replaced by a "<"?

Comment: Yes but the preview was buggy with '<' so I replaced it

Comment: Don't use <pre> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Indeed, if your group is `http` then change the instructions to `http`.
2. Secondly, gitserver in the tutorial is the domain name. Change it to whatever you want.